# sed: replace many lines from a file with single notification

Tags: awk, sed

I'm looking for a solution in GNU `sed`, but POSIX `sed` is OK and `awk` will be OK but probably more complicated than necessary. I prefer sed for this, it should be easy but I'm stuck. Seems like a one-liner can do this, no need to create a python/bash script or anything.

#### my attempted solution

```
  sed -i '218,226140d; 218i ...REMOVED...' psql.log
```

This deletes the desired rows, but the insert gets lost. If I move the insert to line 217 I get:

```
  sed -i '218,226140d; 217i ...REMOVED...' psql.log
```

result:

```
  ┌────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
  │ col_one    │     col_two         │ column_three    │
  ├────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
  │ CC00CBSNRY │           553854451 │       15003.44  │
  │ CC00CBSNRY │          1334177150 │        5159.57  │
  ...REMOVED...
  │ CC6XDSQGH2 │         42385958605 │ [null]          │ (line 217 in original file)
  │ CC6XJ8YG5C │         24661013005 │ [null]          │ (line 226141 in original file) 
  │ CC6XJ9HGRG │         44946564505 │ [null]          │
  │ CC6XMQW6SJ │         34496719615 │ [null]          │
  └────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

I know - this should be good enough, but I'm annoyed that I can't get this simple one-liner to work right. What am I missing?

#### the problem

I keep the `psql.log` file as a reference for work I am doing developing SQL code. It's very useful to see iterations of the query and the results.

The problem is that sometimes I forget to limit the output and the query will generate 100k+ rows of results that aren't a helpful reference, and I'd like to delete them from my file, leaving a note that reminds me the query output has been excised.

It would be nice to match the pattern, say every output more than 50 rows I could squash down to just the first 5 rows and the last 5.  However, its easy for me to mark the line numbers where I've blown up the file, so I'd be happy with just using sed to delete lines N through M, and insert the message `...REMOVED...` where line N was.

Here is an example log file, added notes are in parentheses. The query text can change and the number of columns can be from 1 to 100 or more:

```
  ...
  ********* QUERY **********
  select      *
  from        table
  where       rnk <= 3
  **************************

  ┌────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
  │ col_one    │     col_two         │ column_three    │
  ├────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
  │ CC00CBSNRY │           553854451 │       15003.44  │
  │ CC00CBSNRY │          1334177150 │        5159.57  │
  │ CC6XDSQGH2 │         42385958605 │ [null]          │ (line 217)
  │ CC6XF2SVWT │         13182280615 │ [null]          │
  (many rows)

  │ CC6XF2XWDT │           995086081 │ [null]          │
  │ CC6XFX3TL1 │         25195177405 │ [null]          │
  │ CC6XJ8YG5C │         24661013005 │ [null]          │  (line 226141)
  │ CC6XJ9HGRG │         44946564505 │ [null]          │
  │ CC6XMQW6SJ │         34496719615 │ [null]          │
  └────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
  (225926 rows)

  ********* QUERY **********
  /* another query begins */

  select * from table where X = 1 limit 20;

  /* well done you remembered to limit the output */
  **************************
  ...
```

#### acceptable output

the query text should all be untouched, and the top/bottom three rows of output kept. The annotation `...REMOVED...` has been added and rows 218 through 226140 have been deleted:

```
  ********* QUERY **********
  select      *
  from        table
  where       rnk <= 3
  **************************

  ┌────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
  │ col_one    │     col_two         │ column_three    │
  ├────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
  │ CC00CBSNRY │           553854451 │       15003.44  │
  │ CC00CBSNRY │          1334177150 │        5159.57  │
  │ CC6XDSQGH2 │         42385958605 │ [null]          │ (line 217 in original file)
  ...REMOVED...
  │ CC6XJ8YG5C │         24661013005 │ [null]          │ (line 226141 in original file)
  │ CC6XJ9HGRG │         44946564505 │ [null]          │
  │ CC6XMQW6SJ │         34496719615 │ [null]          │
  └────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
  (225926 rows)

  ********* QUERY **********
  (etc just like example above)
```

#### update

- the border comes from my .psqlrc with `\pset border 2`
- therefore solutions depending on the `┌` character are fragile but OK
- over time i've learned that manually flagging the line numbers is too time consuming, so the best solution needs a pattern match

Comment: Which pattern you wish to match if you directly don't want to go with the line number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One in awk:

```
$ awk '
/^  └/ {                  # at the end marker
    for(j=1;j<=6;j++)     # output from the buffer b the wanted records
        print b[j]
    for(j=(i-2);j<=i;j++) 
        print b[j]
    delete b              # reset buffer
    i=0                   # and flag / counter
} 
/^  ┌/ || i {             # at the start marker or when flag up
    b[++i]=$0             # gather records to buffer
    next
} 1' file                 # print records which are not between the markers
```

Comment: This is what I am using for my log files now as a minor maintenance chore. This is the best solution as time goes by and psql.log files start blowing up.  I posted an answer below which best and most succintly answers the original question, but I'm accepting this answer because it best solves the pattern challenge.

Answer (score 2):

There is example 'every output more than 50 rows I could squash down to just the first 5 rows and the last 5'.

With test input:

```
$ seq 160 | awk -vstart=10 -vmax=50 -vleft=5 '{if(NR < start) {print; next} {i++; if(i <= left || i > max - left){print}; if(i == left + 1){print "...REMOVED..."}if(i == max){i = 0}}}'
```

If you line put script in file, store this to squash.awk

```
BEGIN {
    start=10;
    max=50;
    left=5;
}

{
    if(NR < start) {
        print;
        next
    }
    i++;
    if(i <= left || i > max - left) {
        print
    }
    if(i == left + 1) {
        print "...REMOVED...";
    }
    if(i == max) {
        i = 0
    }
}
```

For testing:

```
$ seq 160 | awk -f squash.awk
```

1. Variable `start` is line number from which squashing line will begin.
2. Variable `max` is maximum rows (in your example 50).
3. Variable `left` is how many rows will left from `max` first and last.
4. `if(NR < start) {print; next}` if line number less then `start` (in our case 10), we just print them and go to next line.
   Here you can put any condition to skip squashing.
5. `i++` it's rows counter increment.
6. `if(i <= left || i > max - left){print}` if rows counter less then 5 or more then `max - 5` - print it.
7. `if(i == left + 1){print "...REMOVED..."}` when we starting skip rows - put "...REMOVED..." message
8. `if(i == max){i = 0}` if rows counter reach `max`, zero it

Comment: thanks for this, its a great reference. however if I'm going to use a script of more complexity we might as well find the offending sections and avoid seeking out the line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/\o342[^\n]*$/{:a;N;//ba;s/^(([^\n]*\n){6}).*((\n[^\n]*){5})$/\1  ... REMOVED ...\3/}' file
```

Focus only on table data which will always contains the octal value `342`. Gather up table lines in the pattern space, substitute the required value `... REMOVED ...` and print. The number of lines above and below the required string can be altered here 6 (headings + 3 rows) and 5 (required string + 3 rows + table count).

To change a range use:

```
sed 'm,nc ... REMOVE ...' file # where m,n from and to line numbers
```

or:

```
sed -e 'ma ...REMOVE ...' -e 'm,nd' file
```

N.B. the `d` command terminates any following commands.

Comment: thank you @potong, this looks interesting. I'm confused by the octal 342 value: `echo "testing octal_342: " | sed -r 's/octal_342/\o342/'` yields `testing ?:`   I don't think the question mark is part of the log file anywhere.

Comment: @Merlin `\o342` is part of a triplet which describes  graphical character such as seen in the table e.g.`\o342\o224\o214` is the first corner of the table as per your example.

Comment: thank you, that's clever! But since the borders to the output can change to simple '\t' depeding on psql settings, probably best to use the literal `**************************` for the pattern match anchor, which will be two lines above the first row of output.

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` man page is more helpful than you might think at first glance. The `[addr]c` command is exactly what is needed *(note the whitespace after c is ignored)*:

```
sed -i '218,226141c ...REMOVED...' psql.log
```

So there is the solution for known line numbers.

Does anyone want to provide a generic solution where the line numbers aren't known? Probably `awk` would be the better tool but maybe `sed` can remove output that is too long.

Comment: This is the best solution for known line numbers, simple and follows the manual.